# Ionic v4 nested tabs

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-router

I'm migrating my app from v3 to v4 and I had nested tabs.

I can't figure it to work, the first level is working just fine, the page of the nested tab is loading fine (without loading its sub tabs) but when I click one of my tab the error

```
ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
     resolvePromise11Angular
```

as when I input a wrong route in a tab.
Here are my routes

app-routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'tab', loadChildren: './pages/main-tabs/main-tabs.module#MainTabsPageModule' },
  ...
];
```

Main tabs modules routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainTabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#tab1PageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#tab2PageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'subTabs',
        loadChildren: '../subTabs/subTabs.module#subTabsPageModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

route in subTabs module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProfilePage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'subTab1',
        loadChildren: '../subTab1/subTab1.module#subTab1PageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'subTab2',
        loadChildren: '../subTab2/subTab2.module#subTab2PageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'subTab3',
        loadChildren: '../subTab3/subTab3.module#subTab3PageModule'
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

When I click on the sub tab I get the error

Each pages are on the same folder. And the links are right since I tested the subTab in the main tab and they work.

```
app
  app-routing.module.ts
  pages
    main-tab
       ...
    tab1
       ...
    tab2
       ...
    subTabs
       ...
    subTab1
       ...
    subTab2
       ...
    subTab3
       ...
    subTab2
       ...
```

The ion-tab-button tab properties has the same name as the path of the right children

Comment: Ok I kinda worked around it and it seems the problems comes from the way ion-tab-button navigate throught the route.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I kinda worked around it and it seems the problems comes from the way ion-tab-button navigate throught the route. 
If I replace the buttons with a simple "a routerlink" on the sub tab it works just fine.

So I'll guess I'll do the navigation manually with a click event and activate the sub tab button manually

Comment: thank you! <a routerLink="/app/tabs/home/map"> works like a charm